# Create array not object in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to pass all the car's service rate with an array not object. There are some cars and their service rate with specific destination is different. I want pass the service rate of destination with an array to later use it with onclick function.
Here is what I am with now

```
$international = [];$i= 0;
foreach($fleets as $fleet){
  foreach($fleet as $flee){
    foreach($flee->serviceRate as $service){
      if($service->destination == 'International Drive/Sea World'){
         $international = Arr::add($international, $i, $service->rate);
         $i++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is returning me an object. I tried array_push, doesn't work. I tried $international->toarray() doesn't work. How can I create an array not object?

Answer (score 0):

why do you looping through all these models if you need only `$flee->serviceRate`? i guess `$flee` reperesents some mode (lets say `Flee` model with relation `serviceRate` to `ServiceRate` model), then

```php
// Illuminate\Support\Collection result
$international = ServiceRate::where('destination', 'International Drive/Sea World')->get();
// if you for some reason want array explicitly
$internationalInArray = $international->toArray();
```

and `count($internationalInArray)` or `$international->count()` will give you results count (`$i` in your example)